# Vlookup/Hlookup possibility in python

Tags: python, django, import-from-excel

I'm curious to know if there's another solution to the problem I'm currently facing.

I have 3 excel sheets(~200 rows each) with two columns of values.

column A = foo Column B = Bar

I have a django app which basically requests the user to enter value 'foo' and python would automatically provide the corresponding value in the row.

I converted all 3 sheets into python dictionaries using xlread.

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(2)   
lookup = dict(zip(sh.col_values(0, 1), sh.col_values(1, 0)))
```

Everything works correctly. Python provides the correct values. But i think i'm missing something out on something which would provide a similar function without converting the sheet into a huge dict object.

Is there anything similar to Excel's Vlookup/Hlookup provided by xlread?

Thanks,
KJ

Comment: Oh .. do you want me to reword the question or the content?

Comment: Your code works already, why change it? `xlread` will have to read the entire file into memory before it could do the lookup anyway (assuming it could), so what is to be gained?

Comment: The problem is that my function converts the entire sheet into a dictionary whenever it is invoked. I'm worried about this being really slow. I wanted a similar way using xlrd to just performing a vlookup like function in the sheet as opposed to creating a dictionary each time